# Creating another user account having power of root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root, sudo

How to create another root account with other name on a Linux system(in my case Ubuntu 13.04).
If i create a ordinary user account and set its UID to 0 in /etc/passwd then it will conflict with root(also has uid 0).so i gave him gid=0(group of root). but didn't worked.
please provid any effective solution.i've also added this user in sudoers file.

Comment: What do you mean by "it will conflict"? What fails? Adding two users with the same uid has worked on UNIX historically and has been done frequently to create "alternate " root accounts. Although I haven't tried it recently, I'm surprised to hear that it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Unix system should have one, and one only, root user. Unix systems are built on that rule.

If you want to promote a user for any reason, the user should use the sudo command.

```
$ sudo <command> <options>
```

Or allow temporary super-user by loging in as the root (use with extreme caution)

```
$ su
```

One should manually edit the sudo configuration to specify which user can do what:

```
$ sudo visudo
```

Then you can add users one by one or add a group of users.

Another way, would be to add users one by one to the sudo group.

```
$ sudo adduser <username> sudo
```

You said you updated the sudoers list. Then your user should be able to run sudo. If not, your configuration might be wrong.

Remember to always log out and in after you modify the current user's sudoers' privileges. Or you will not see any difference.

Regards,
Arthur

Comment: Not answering the question.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92123/rsync-all-files-of-remote-machine-over-ssh-without-root-user#comment170839_92397 argues in favour of distinct root accounts if different users require SSH root privileges and distinct shell, home and `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: It is really not answering the question. I know one reason to have a second root account: it is easy to mess up the sudoers file. This prevents sudo from working. If you do not have the original root's password (because for instance that is guarded by your hosting company) a second one is quite a lifesaver.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a new user same like root user. 
try following steps

Let's assume you want to create a new user admin with root privileges.
Log-in on the Linux machine as root.

@ useradd  admin

@ vi /etc/passwd

Change the XXX with 0. as per following screenshot i.e. - from admin:x:506:512::/home/admin:/bin/bash to admin:x:0:0::/home/admin:/bin/bash
create a user in Linux with root privileges

Logout from root user and login with admin user again

I am unable to format this post and upload image here. I have solution on this link as well.

http://www.kriblog.com/linux/how-to-create-a-user-in-linux-with-root-privileges.html

Comment: I wouldn't recommend editing `/etc/passwd` manually. A simple mistake here can make you **unable to log into your system**

Answer (score 0):

**For Example we want to add a user `john` with the sudo power**

> Simply Follow These Steps

```
$ sudo useradd -ou 0 -g 0 john
$ sudo passwd john
```